# What is the usage difference between a structure and a list ADT?

Tags: c++, abstract-data-type, data-stream

As the title suggests, I am currently working on a project which carries data in the forum of a "DataStream" variable which is a "list ADT" which is used to store data packets to send between routers through a Datastream.

Why would use declare it as a list ADT instead of creating a data structure including all the different data variables within the packet? Are there any main benefits for doing this or does it give you extra functionality compared to declaring it as a data structure?

Answer (score 0):

I found a good answer which pretty much describes what an ADT is within a general term.

http://iampandiyan.blogspot.in/2013/11/what-is-abstract-data-typeadt.html